# Change count++ from 1 to 0.0001 php

Tags: php, while-loop

i have a while loop, whereby when a result is submitted it will automatically check if there is a similar result and add 0.0001 to the result, however when i use count++ it will add 1 instead of 0.0001.

```
$count = 0.0001;
$sql1 = "select score from CF where trainee = '$selectedoption' 
and score = $totalresult";

$score = mysql_query($sql1);
$num2 = mysql_num_rows($score);

while ($num2 > 0)
{
$newtotal = $totalresult + $count;
$sql1 = "select score from CF where trainee = '$selectedoption' 
    and score = '$newtotal'";
    $score = mysql_query($sql1);
    $num2 = mysql_num_rows($score);
    $count++;
}
```

Comment: So replace `$count++;` with `$count += 0.0001;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operator ++ will always add 1. To add 0.0001 you can use the following statement:

```
$count += 0.0001;
```

This is short for

```
$count = $count + 0.0001;
```

Answer (score 0):

The increment operator (++) will always add 1.  To increment by a different amount you need to state that explicitly.  As in

```
$count = $count + 0.0001;
```

Or define a function to do that for you.